# signature not signed with a trusted key

Tags: kernel, xorg

My X11 Desktop crashed for the same reason these days

```
/var/log/kern.log:Oct  9 14:55:29 alpha kernel: [   51.560789] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
/var/log/kern.log:Oct 10 20:53:30 alpha kernel: [    1.316375] Initialise system trusted keyrings
/var/log/kern.log:Oct 10 20:53:30 alpha kernel: [    1.566875] Key type trusted registered
/var/log/kern.log:Oct 10 20:53:30 alpha kernel: [   49.866048] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
/var/log/kern.log:Oct 10 20:53:31 alpha kernel: [   52.359018] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
/var/log/kern.log:Oct 10 20:53:31 alpha kernel: [   52.607128] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
/var/log/kern.log:Oct 10 20:53:31 alpha kernel: [   52.609413] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
/var/log/kern.log:Oct 10 20:53:31 alpha kernel: [   52.611961] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
/var/log/kern.log:Oct 11 05:21:14 alpha kernel: [    1.332628] Initialise system trusted keyrings
/var/log/kern.log:Oct 11 05:21:14 alpha kernel: [    1.586145] Key type trusted registered
/var/log/kern.log:Oct 11 05:21:14 alpha kernel: [   48.973431] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
/var/log/kern.log:Oct 11 05:21:15 alpha kernel: [   51.242295] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
/var/log/kern.log:Oct 11 05:21:15 alpha kernel: [   51.496355] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
/var/log/kern.log:Oct 11 05:21:15 alpha kernel: [   51.499499] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
/var/log/kern.log:Oct 11 05:21:15 alpha kernel: [   51.504483] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
/var/log/kern.log:Oct 11 14:42:55 alpha kernel: [    1.332616] Initialise system trusted keyrings
/var/log/kern.log:Oct 11 14:42:55 alpha kernel: [    1.590843] Key type trusted registered
/var/log/kern.log:Oct 11 14:42:55 alpha kernel: [   48.803714] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
/var/log/kern.log:Oct 11 14:42:56 alpha kernel: [   51.291135] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
/var/log/kern.log:Oct 11 14:42:56 alpha kernel: [   51.536567] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
/var/log/kern.log:Oct 11 14:42:56 alpha kernel: [   51.540598] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
/var/log/kern.log:Oct 11 14:42:56 alpha kernel: [   51.543458] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
/var/log/kern.log:Oct 11 19:55:41 alpha kernel: [    1.332554] Initialise system trusted keyrings
/var/log/kern.log:Oct 11 19:55:41 alpha kernel: [    1.592800] Key type trusted registered
/var/log/kern.log:Oct 11 19:55:41 alpha kernel: [   48.956084] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
/var/log/kern.log:Oct 11 19:55:42 alpha kernel: [   51.173503] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
/var/log/kern.log:Oct 11 19:55:42 alpha kernel: [   51.414123] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
/var/log/kern.log:Oct 11 19:55:42 alpha kernel: [   51.416660] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
/var/log/kern.log:Oct 11 19:55:42 alpha kernel: [   51.419845] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
/var/log/syslog:Oct  9 10:16:58 alpha kernel: [    1.316754] Initialise system trusted keyrings
```

My machine:

```
$ neofetch
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               gaowei@alpha
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ------------
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 19.04 x86_64
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: MacBookPro11,1 1.0
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.0.0-29-generic
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 19 hours, 52 mins
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 2367 (dpkg), 4 (snap)
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 5.0.3
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 2560x1600
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: KDE
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: KWin
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Theme: Breeze [KDE], Breeze [GTK3]
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Icons: breeze [KDE], breeze [GTK3]
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Terminal: alacritty
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     CPU: Intel i5-4258U (4) @ 2.900GHz
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      GPU: Intel Haswell-ULT
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Memory: 2457MiB / 3850MiB
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`
```

Comment: Does it crash during boot or during utilization ? It could crash during boot but if the boot succeed, i'm not sure if these PKCS#7 signature errors are related.

Comment: Did you upgrade your Mac to Catalina recently? Mac's typically come with a T2 chip that enforces secure boot and digital signature enforcement, so I'm not sure if anything changed the way that Apple treats EFI modules that were not made by Apple. You could try to temporarily turn secure boot off to see if that mitigates the problem. See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208330 for how to change secure boot settings.

Comment: @darksky ty, but my machine is bought in 2013 which does not have s security chip.